# Using mem_fun_ref if member function requires multiple parameters

Tags: c++

Unfortunately, I cannot use C++11 or Boost.

I have some code like the following

```
struct Cell
{
    Cell(int value) : value(value) {}

    int value;

    bool CompareValue(const Cell& other) const
    {
        return this->value < other.value;
    }
};

int main()
{
    const int size = 10;
    vector<Cell> cells;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cells.push_back(Cell(rand()));
        cout << "[ " << cells.back().value << " ] ";
    }
    cout << "\n\n";

    int maxvalue = max_element(cells.begin(), cells.end(), mem_fun_ref(&Cell::CompareValue))->value;
    int minvalue = min_element(cells.begin(), cells.end(), mem_fun_ref(&Cell::CompareValue))->value;

    cout << "Max = " << maxvalue << "\n" << "Min = " << minvalue << "\n";
}
```

But now I need to expand the compare function to take a compare MODE

```
bool CompareValue(const Cell& other, MODE_T mode) const
{
    switch (mode)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

However, I cannot figure out how to update the use of max_element to work with this new function. The mode parameter will be the same for each run of comparisons. I tried using various bind and stuff but to no avail. Any help appreciated.

Comment: How about std::tr1? Can you change call to some predicate, instead of call member-function directly?

Comment: If it works in Visual Studio 2008 and gcc, I can use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write `functor`, that will does such thing.

```
struct CompareCellWithMode : public std::binary_function<Cell, Cell, bool>
{
public:
   result_type CompareCellWithMode
   (const first_argument_type& f, const second_argument_type& s)
   {
      return f.CompareValue(s, mode);
   }
private:
   MODE_T mode;
};

MODE_T mode;
int maxvalue = max_element(cells.begin(), 
cells.end(), CompareCellWithMode(mode))->value;
```

or with `std::tr1::bind`

```
MODE_T mode;
int maxvalue = max_element(cells.begin(), cells.end(), 
std::tr1::bind(&Cell::CompareValue, _1, mode))->value;
```

Comment: I am having difficulty with _1, the compiler cannot find it.

Comment: @NeilKirk try `std::tr1::placeholders::_1`.